# How to get around people changing form submit methods

Tags: php, html, forms, routes

I've got the following HTML

```
<form action="/home" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
    <input type="text" name="var">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

on the server side, I trigger different actions based on the type of request I get. The `_method` hidden field governs that action. Can users not simply change the value to, say `DELETE` and cause mayhem? I tried it on my local Apache server, and **it does** in fact trigger the delete route, which could potentially be disastrous.

I also know that I'm **not** the only one using this practice, as I've seen it on official documentations for various frameworks, so what am I missing?

Comment: That is their problem, they should only be able to delete their own stuff anyway. You could of course add a csrf token, like a hash based on the route that the form is supposed to take and check that in the controller. That's always a good idea.

Comment: that actually sounds like a good idea. Something like sha1('get', 'some secret key') I suppose

Comment: short answer, no. You cannot prevent what and how the client will send things to your server as it is all client side. All you can do is sanitize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the method name on the server side with:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    // collect value of input field
}
else{
   // Do nothing
}
?>
```

**Note:** Change "GET" as you see fit.

**Note2:** $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] is generated by the server. User can not edit it. So, you can check with this variable what kind of request you have (GET, POST, PUT,...).

Hope it helps you!

Comment: That doesn't change much, a user can change the form's method just as easily as a hidden field.

Comment: Wouldn't this be pointless because I don't have just one route to perform actions on. I want the /home to be able to accept post, put, delete, and get  requests. The 'request method' offset is practically controlled by the user who can change it to whatever he wants.

Comment: \_action is useless in my answer, you can delete it in your form. So, if user changes the method name, for example, does a POST request, _if statement_ will not collect data because $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] will be "POST".